# 3D animation of a parametrized curve

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib, 3d

I'm a beginner in Python. My aim is to create a 3D animation in which the position vector (in 3D coordinate system) would follow the trajectory of a parametrized curve as the parameter t moves from a to b. I know that matplotlib has a 3D animation toolkit but still I wonder if such work is within its capabilities.

I'd be glad to hear your opinion.

Comment: If you want to plot the trajectory of the point, shouldn't plot the 3d curve be enough? I have not understood what you're asking...

Comment: Later on, I hope to extend the animation to calculus concepts such as line integral for educative reasons. What I'd like to observe is that the position vector pointing to each point on the curve as it follows the trajectory in time.

Comment: Matplotlib is capable of animating lines and points in 3D. However, it will need explicit coordinates in the form `plt.plot(x,y,z)`. `x, y, z` can be a function of time. If your curve has an implicit parametric form, f(x,y,z)=0, you would first need to find a means to bring it to an explicit one.

Comment: I see, thank you for your help.